# Why does 'apt' do not store downloaded packages anymore?

Tags: linux, apt-get, apt

I was used to `apt` storing downloaded packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`, but it does not do it anymore and I can't figure out why.

Configuration is set accordingly IMHO:

```
# apt-config dump | grep -i cache
Dir::Cache "var/cache/apt";
Dir::Cache::archives "archives/";
Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "srcpkgcache.bin";
Dir::Cache::pkgcache "pkgcache.bin";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache "";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::Show "";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::Show::Version "2";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::AllVersions "0";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::ShowVirtuals "1";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::Search "";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::Search::Version "2";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::ShowDependencyType "1";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::ShowVersion "1";
```

Although I don't know about the `Binary::*` stuff.

It does not seem to be related to any permission issue as well, because `/var/cache/apt/archives/` is recreated when using `apt install <arbitrary-package>`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [dedicated setting](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/1.8.2/debian/NEWS#L109) for this which appeared in 2016 (that is including the Debian 9 stable release):

> ```
> apt (1.2~exp1) experimental; urgency=medium
>
>   [ Automatic removal of debs after install ]
>   After packages are successfully installed by apt(8),
>   the corresponding .deb package files will be
>   removed from the /var/cache/apt/archives cache directory.
>
>   This can be changed by setting the apt configuration option
>     "Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages" to "true". E.g:
>
>   # echo 'Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";' \
>       > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs
>
>   Please note that the behavior of apt-get is unchanged. The
>   downloaded debs will be kept in the cache directory after they
>   are installed. To enable the behavior for other tools, you can set
>   "APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages" to false.
> ```

So there are two toggles:

the `apt` command specific toggle:

```
Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages
```

which can be set to `"true"` to change `apt`'s default.

and the global toggle:

```
APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages
```

which can be set to `"false"` to change among other tools `apt-get`'s default.

So if for example you want to completely invert the current behaviours of `apt` ("don't keep" to "keep") and `apt-get` ("keep" to "don't keep") in Debian 10, you'd add this somewhere in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`:

```
Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";
APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "false";
```

Note: if the file was already present (eg: previously downloaded with `--download-only`), it's possible the settings won't have any effect and the file will stay. This might depend on `apt`'s version. The behaviour is consistent at least when the command downloads the package *and* installs it.

Answer (score 2):

[Rubber duck asking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) worked. While writing the two last paragraphs, I realised that `apt install` works differently to `apt-get install` in this context.

The manpage of `apt` explains this (emphasis mine):

> All features of apt(8) are available in dedicated APT tools like apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8) as well. apt(8) just **changes the default** value of some options (see apt.conf(5) and specifically the **Binary scope**).

(See also section `BINARY SPECIFIC CONFIGURATION` in `man apt.conf`.)

Unfortunately the behaviour does not change, although I added these two lines to a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`:

```
Binary::apt::APT::Cache "/var/cache/apt";
Binary::apt::APT::Cache::Archives "archives";
```